# Best way to save user info on server using oauth on Android

Tags: android, oauth

I am developing an android app that will allow users to login in via their Google account. The only problem, is that I want to create this user on the server and save their info on there. How should I go about doing this? I was thinking of having the user login in through the android app, then retrieve the token and send it to the server, but from there I am not sure if you can use the token to get user info.

Answer (score 0):

add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile in the scopes,

and after user's authorization, get https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=youraccess_token

then you'll get a json contains user info.

{
"id": "00000000000000",
"email": "fred.example@gmail.com",
"verified_email": true,
"name": "Fred Example",
"given_name": "Fred",
"family_name": "Example",
"picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2Sv-4bBMLLA/bEG4kI2mG0I/photo.jpg",
"gender": "male",
"locale": "en-US"
}